# is learning the win32 API and MFC worthwhile for a Qt developer?

Tags: winapi, qt, mfc

I am an expert Qt Developer and i know most of its classes and functions. But i think it is at a high level of abstraction. so i decided to learn win32 APIs and MFC, is my decision good or bad ? and why ?
thanks

Comment: This is really hard to objectively answer. Generally though it's never bad to learn anything. And I guess you're the only one who can really answer the question. Is there a need for you to know about them? Will you use them soon? See any use for it in your future? If so, great. If it's just curiosity, great.

Comment: @eznme: now on to your credit card....muwhahaha

Comment: Learn MFC if you want to see how not to design a GUI framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at learning the WinAPI and MFC as two mutually exclusive things in your case. MFC is designed to be an abstraction layer over the WinAPI for RAD, much like Qt (although obviously not AS abstract). If you're an expert in Qt, I would think there would be little value in learning MFC.

However, understanding the WinAPI and how Windows works "internally" at a level below the framework wrappers would provide some valuable knowledge. You would know "how" the frameworks achieve what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Qt is a cross platform framework and has nothing to do with win32. As you said, Qt abstracts away the platform so the only reason you might want to learn MFC is to write low level software for windows or to maintain existing (very) old code...that targets windows.
Updated: I don't have much experience with Qt (only 1 data driven application) and only academic experience with MFC so I have no idea if it is a good time investment career-wise.

Comment: Can only speak for myself, but knowing how the Win32 API works under the hood has helped me to predict Qt's reactions and how to implement something several times. Now that's good (you get a working solution) and bad (these are obviously not clearly documented and may result in non-optimal code for other platforms), but it can be useful

Answer (score 1):

Not MFC but learning atl and com+ could be useful. If you're programming windows applications with c++, you may need COM+.